# how could I replace string in the KMZ file by using powershell

Tags: powershell, kml, replace, unzip, kmz

I need to modify the property string in KML/KMZ file, 
I have unzip the KMZ file to the temp folder and need to go through the KML file to change the name string, (all the name string when it apprears) so powershell could help, but I am not quite sure how, I am a newbie in powershell.
how could I do this? please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a sample this example isn't accurate but you have to do something like this:

```
(get-content c:\temp\yourfile.kml ) | % {  $_ -replace 'name','anothername' } | 
set-content c:\temp\yourfile.kml
```

This change ANY 'name' string with 'anothername' string:

```
myname it's my name
```

become

```
myanothername it's my anothername
```

Comment: FYI - You can do it without ForEach-Object: `(get-content c:\temp\yourfile.kml) -replace 'name', 'anothername' | Set-Content C:\temp\yourfile.kml`. You might want to mention since OP is a PS beginner, that the -replace operator uses regex's so certain characters in the search string may have to be escaped.

Comment: @AndyArismendi Thank you for the precisations... anyways feel free to edit my answers adding your valuable suggestions. I would be honored.